# DavLockDB Not Created Despite Correct Permissions

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, centos-7, webdav

Coming back to Linux after years away and trying to set up `mod_dav` to serve myself the `/var/www` directory to do some web development. Should be easy, but this is giving me a hard time. Running CentOS 7 on an AWS Lightsail instance. Installed `httpd` and `mod_ssl` via `yum` and performed what should have been an easy config.

In `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` global section:

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock
```

In `<VirtualHost>`:

```
Alias /webdav /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I have done a `chown 777 apache:apache` on `/var/www`. I have run `systemctl restart apache` and rebooted, but no luck.

Now for the weird stuff. I can get successfully log in from a Windows 10 client and get a listing of directories in `/var/www` on `<mydomain>/webdav`. I can list and open files in `/var/www`, but not in `/var/www/html`. I cannot create files or directories.

In `ssl_error.log`:

```
[Sun May 24 20:01:49.254447 2020] [dav:error] [pid 16108] [client <masked ip>] The locks could not be queried for verification against a possible "If:" header.  [500, #0]
[Sun May 24 20:01:49.254463 2020] [dav:error] [pid 16108] [client <masked ip>] Could not open the lock database.  [500, #400]
[Sun May 24 20:01:49.254473 2020] [dav:error] [pid 16108] (13)Permission denied: [client <masked ip>] Could not open property database.  [500, #1]
```

OK. So the permissions aren't right to create the lock database. But `ls -la` returns this:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 apache apache   33 May 24 19:49 www
```

And to double dummy-check, `ps -aux` shows httpd is running as user apache, minus the startup process it needs to bind the ports:

```
root     16107  0.0  1.4 249968  7416 ?        Ss   20:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16108  0.0  1.1 250236  5652 ?        S    20:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16109  0.0  0.7 249968  3644 ?        S    20:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16110  0.0  0.7 249968  3644 ?        S    20:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16111  0.0  0.7 249968  3644 ?        S    20:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16112  0.0  1.1 250236  5656 ?        S    20:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   16116  0.0  0.7 249968  3656 ?        S    20:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

What the heck am I missing?

Comment: Ok, so part one is figured out. SELinux was preventing Apache from writing the lock file. Anyone else who has this problem, the changes necessary are here: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=httpd&f=12

Still need to figure out why I cannot see files in the html folder, though...

Comment: So it seems to only affect the `/var/www/html` folder. I can successfully access and edit `/var/www/cgi-bin`. Is it because `/var/www/html` is the root for the virtual host and WebDAV is serving an upstream directory as an alias? I've tried adding another `Alias` and another `<Directory>`, both of which did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

So this was a two-parter:

1. First, as I metioned in a comment above, SELinux was not allowing the Apache process to write the DavLock file. Instructions on how to correct this without disabling SELinux: https://server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=httpd&f=12
2. Second, directory indexes cannot be on for any folder you want served via WebDAV. There was `DirectoryIndex index.html` in my main httpd.conf file and this was screwing things up. By adding the following to `<Directory /var/www/html>` block everything started working:

```
    <If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} != 'GET'">
        DirectoryIndex none
    </If>
    <Else>
        DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html
    </Else>
```